# Change chrome settings (PDF Documents setting) using java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I used to be able to click on a button and a PDF file downloaded and then I was able to read it. 
However, now the PDF opens up in the browser which makes it difficult to read from there because I get a 401. 
I noticed that I can change the chrome settings to that the PDF document downloads instead of opening in the browser.
There is a toggle in chrome settings (PDF Documents - "Download PDF Files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome"). This can be found in `chrome://settings`/.

How can I change it using selenium?
Can I use `ChromeOptions`? if yes, how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Whyoneearth. Do see my answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `ChromeOptions` to change the chrome default pdf download setting by using the code below:

```
 HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
 chromePrefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);  // Download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();  
 options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);  

 DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
 cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);  

 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "driverpath\\chromedriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can indeed access the chrome settings menu and change options as you like. This is because the setting is simply a rendered HTML DOM, you can verify that by pressing `F12` and going to `Elements` section. see below for an example case.

I used `.elementToBeClickable()` in my code below. This is perfect since you want to simply toggle the button. The `.until()` returns the element waited for so you can just append `.click()` on the end of the statement.

```
driverChrome.manage().window().maximize();
driverChrome.get("chrome://settings");
WebElement w = driverChrome.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='settings']"));
driverChrome = driverChrome.switchTo().frame(w);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driverChrome, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[text()='Show advanced settings...']"))).click();//****replace the text here
```

As you can see, I access the chrome settings and within that, I set an XPath to the text of the button (you may change this if you like). This the clicks/toggle the element and in your case will set whether to open in chrome or to download it.